# Get Altitude for Multiple Objects

Tags: qgis, altitude

I use QGIS and I has two layers: one with point objects (more than 1000) and one with surface (it is a version of DCW). I want compute altitude of all points. Basically, I want to get an array where every objects from the first layer comes with its altitude. Please recommend the most handy way to accomplish this result.

Answer (score 1):

The process you're describing is called point sampling, and there's a QGIS plugin called `Point Sampling Tool` which you can download from the plugin manager.
[image]

Make sure that the point layer and the raster have the same CRS